# this as reference in Object assignment

Tags: java, this

I know that this question could look a bit trivial with an obvious answer, but i could't find any explanation around, nor on StackOverflow nor on Google.

The following code:

```
Object o = this;
```

Can it be used inside a Class method (an instance method belonging to a generic Class, not a Static method) which needs to manipulate (let's say with a for-loop) Object o updating its reference during each iteration?

Again, consider the following code assuming we have an Array `MyObject[] oArr` and `otherMethod` is available to MyObject:

```
MyObject obj = this;
for(MyObject f : oArr){
    obj = obj.otherMethod(f);
}
```

What is happening here is:

- this is used to assign to `obj` a reference to the current object executing the method
- once the reference is assigned, we can finally update the reference of the object o during each iteration

To be completely honest what is confusing me here is this line of code:

```
MyObject obj = this;
```

It's the first time ever that i find `this` without a variable/method name, used to simply reference an object.

**Did i get right what is going on here? Am i missing anything? Do you have a link where i can find additional info about similar uses of `this`?**
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "class method"? A `static` method (which is what that phrase means) or an instance method?

Comment: you always work with pointer, you never clone an object when assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I mean an instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot access `this` in a `class`(`static`) method, because `this` simply does not exist in the context of `static` methods.

AFTER EDIT:

However, `this` is an object of the current class in context. So, it is OK to assign it to another variable.

Comment: Never said the code was in a static method :) I'm going to update the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing "wrong" about assigning `this` to a variable.

In your case, doing so sets up the initial conditions for your iterative code.

A reasonable such usage may be in a linked list, where the root node is `this`:

```
// find end node, to add another node perhaps
Node node = this;
while (node.next != null)
    node = node.next;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyObject obj = this;
```

this also can be used to point to constructors, so in here `this` is used to refernce to class which this line is in the context of, but the refernced class should be same type / have a inheritance relatinship in order to refernce, to be clear
assume you write this line in `AClass`

```
class AClass {
  MyObject obj= this; // in here you refer the AClass by calling this,
}
```

Comment: -1: this doesn't refer to constructors, and this doesn't reference a class either. And you don't "call" this.

Comment: so what is this referring ?

Comment: `this` is referring to the current object.

Comment: actually we are talking about same context, i said this is used to refernce to class in here i mean current instance of that classi ah btw you can use this to reference constructors http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: But your example doesn't show any constructor chaining, and your terminology is still confusing. A class and an instance of a class are not the same thing at all, and using one to mean the other is wrong.

Comment: yes i know, it's my bad, ah by the way my example not the full code, it's just an excerpt example